# Scheduling function calls in a Python curses UI

Tags: python, curses

I'm trying to write a program that will have a curses interface (so I can easily change settings on the fly) and will also be able to call and display the output of functions called on different schedules.

I can't figure out how to efficiently call something on a set time period and still use a curses loop that can take input at any time.

Here's an example of a small program that attempts to do what I'm saying. (doesn't work)

```
import curses, sched, time

from datetime import datetime

def show_time(sc):
    screen.addstr(12, 12, datetime.now())
    sc.enter(1, 1, show_time, (sc,))

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(0)
screen.keypad(1)

screen.addstr("This is a Sample Curses Script\n\n")

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
s.enter(1, 1, show_time, (s,))
s.run()
while True:
   event = screen.getch()
   if event == ord("q"): break

curses.endwin()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your script seems to have two problems.

1. This line:

   ```
   screen.addstr(12, 12, datetime.now())
   ```

   will raise a `TypeError` since `addstr` expect a `str` not a `datetime`, so you need to replace that line with something like:

   ```
   screen.addstr(12, 12, time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M"))
   ```
2. The second problem is that recursive sched calling:

   ```
   sc.enter(1, 1, show_time, (sc,))
   ```

   I never used the sched module, but I expanded my knowledge a bit and it seems that the `.run()` will stop untill all the scheduled events are completed.

If you're only interested in updating your screen every second, why don't you try something like:

```
import curses
import time
import threading

def update_time(screen):
    while 1:
        screen.addstr(12, 12, time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))
        screen.refresh()
        time.sleep(1)

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(0)
screen.keypad(1)

screen.addstr("This is a Sample Curses Script\n\n")
screen.refresh()

clock = threading.Thread(target=update_time, args=(screen,))
clock.daemon = True
clock.start()
while 1:
    event = screen.getch()
    if event == ord("q"):
        break

curses.endwin()
```

Comment: The recursive calling is the only way I've seen to be able to repeat a sched call for an event.  I'm afraid if I put it into the while True loop, it will mess up the scheduling.

Comment: @user1209675: If you're only interested in updating your screen, and don't care if it's with the `sched` module or not, why don't you try to use threads? I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to solve this is to use GNU readline for your input rather than the default curses input. Then use the async capability of `readline` so that you have a `select` loop from which you can call functions.

First of all, the Python readline library doesn't support async readline function calls, however [it is easy to interface Python directly to readline using `ctypes`](http://wavetossed.blogspot.com/2011/07/asynchronous-gnu-readline.html).

That way you have a select loop that is always in control. When there is no input, check the clock to see if it is time to run your function. If not, sleep for a few milliseconds, check for a keystroke, look at the clock and sleep again. `time.sleep` can handle fractional seconds.